# I can't find my installed Ibus "Keyboard Input Methods" in Dash

Tags: ibus

I have installed ibus Keyboard Input Methods, but I can't find it anywhere in the Dash, 
so I can't open and use it.

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The package name of the Keyboard Input Methods program is ibus. Keyboard Input Methods is a program used to adjust methods for keyboard input. IBus normally automatically starts up at login. To use IBus open any GUI application e.g. gedit, LibreOffice Writer, etc. and start typing in the text input area.

Otherwise ibus can be accessed either from *Systems Settings* -> *Language Support* -> *Language* tab -> dropdown menu to the right of where it says *Keyboard input method system:* or from the terminal by typing `ibus`.

If this information isn't sufficient for your purposes, then please provide additional information about what you are trying to use Keyboard Input Methods to do. For example, changing the keyboard input language, if you are using more than one text entry language, can be done quickly using the keyboard combination <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. The Super key has a Microsoft Windows logo on it in many keyboards.

To add the Hindi language go to *Systems Settings* -> *Text Entry* -> under *Input sources to use:* click Hindi. Then click the little keyboard icon to open the **Hindi** window and display the Hindi keyboard layout. Is the Hindi keyboard layout displayed in the Hindi window? If the Hindi keyboard layout isn't displayed in the Hindi window, you can add it by clicking on the plus button (**+**) to open the **Choose an input source** window, selecting the Hindi language from the list of keyboard input languages, and then clicking the **Add** button to add the Hindi language to the language selection menu that is in the notification area of the desktop panel next to the volume icon and the clock icon.

[image]
<sup>**Make sure that "Show current input source in the menu bar" is marked by a check mark.**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Add Hindi keyboard layout**</sup>

---

English translation of Monika von Birkenstein's output from running the command `ibus` from the terminal. Translated and posted below because it wouldn't fit in Monika's first comment, so this is a continuation of that comment.

```
Usage: ibus COMMAND [OPTION...]

Commands:
  engine         Set or get engine
  exit           Exit ibus-daemon
  list-engine    Show available engines
  watch          (Not implemented)
  restart        Restart ibus-daemon
  version        Show version
  read-cache     Show the content of registry cache
  write-cache    Create registry cache
  address        Print the D-Bus address of ibus-daemon
  help           Show this information
```

Comment: [repost of Monika von Birkenstein's comment] Well, that is my problem: If I type `ibus` in the Dash there is nothing. And it doesn't start automatically at login. And if I go to Systems Settings -> Language Support -> Language tab, there is a sign that says I am using Ibus, but I'm not. If I type `ibus` in the terminal, then there is this (I'm using Ubuntu in Dutch): Gebruik: ibus OPDRACHT [OPTIE...] ... really can't find or start or use Ibus anywhere on my computer. I would like to use it to type Hindi in LibreOffice Writer

Comment: I have installed the hindi keybord layout. How can I type in Hindi now?

Comment: @MonikavonBirkenstein I installed the Hindi keyboard layout on my computer and I could type right away, no reboot required. The only thing I don't know is which of the three Hindi input sources is the best one. I tested it on the first input source, Hindi (Bolnagri). You can add an input source by clicking on the plus button (+) and remove an input source by clicking on the minus button (-) until you find which Hindi input source you want.

Comment: I still can't type in Hindi. My computer is cursed, I guess. I'll give up, still thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you at least use the Ubuntu built-in **Onboard** app to display a virtual keyboard in the Hindi language after adding the Hindi language, and type in Hindi using the mouse and the Onboard virtual keyboard?

Comment: No I can't type using the mouse. And my screen looks different, but I can't post a screenshot because I don't have 10 reputation. On my computer it's called: Alle Instellingen < Regio en Taal < Invoerbronnen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is my problem: if i typ 'ibus' in the dash there is nothing. And it doens't start automatically at login. And if I go to Systems Settings -> Language Support -> Language tab, there is a sign that says I am using Ibus, but I'm not. If I typ ibus in the terminal, then there is this (I'm using ubuntu in Dutch):

```
Gebruik: ibus OPDRACHT [OPTIE...]

Opdrachten:
  engine         Stel programmamotor in of haal deze op
  exit           Verlaat ibus-achtergronddienst
  list-engine    Toon beschikbare programmamotoren
  watch          (Niet geïmplementeerd)
  restart        Start ibus-achtergronddienst opnieuw op
  version        Toon versie
  read-cache     Toon de inhoud van tijdelijke opslag van register
  write-cache    Maak tijdelijke opslag van register aan
  address        Druk het D-Bus-adres af van ibus-achtergronddienst
  help           Toon deze informatie
```

I really can't find or start or use Ibus anywhere on my computer. I would like to use it to type Hindi in LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: If you have additional information, please edit your question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I translated Monika's answer. I got the translation from the terminal by running the same command ( `ibus ` ) and then checked it using Google translate. Then I added everything to my own answer, so now everyone can read this in English.

Comment: @MonikavonBirkenstein I added info about how to type in Hindi to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ibus is integrated into Text Entry in later versions of Ubuntu.

Go to System Settings » Text Entry » Click the " + " sign » Search hindi

and you're good to go.